# How to get the years from an array of dates in order

Tags: javascript, date

I have this array:

```
var array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];
```

How can I get the years from it in order? So the result would be this:

```
result = ['2020','2021','2022'];
```

Do I have to change the array to a new Date() format and sort, or how would be the best way ? Any Suggestion ?

Comment: you want to get only `years` and sort them? or you want `month` too?

Comment: I just need the years

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a combination of `...` , `Set` , `.map()` and  `.sort()`. This can be done in one line.

`...` -> destructures array into individual items.

`new Set()` -> make a set out of the new items.

`map()` -> runs a loop and map the array into a new one.

`split()` -> breaks a string into array.

`sort()` -> sorts an array.

```js
var array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];

console.log([...new Set(array1.map(x => x.split('/')[1]))].sort());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this result using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array1 = [
  "9/2022",
  "7/2020",
  "11/2021",
  "12/2020",
  "2/2020",
  "4/2021",
  "10/2021",
];

const result = [...new Set(array1.map((s) => s.split("/")[1]))].sort();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can map to get only the years, and then sort the results. Then you instantiate a Set which removes all duplicate entries.

```js
new Set(['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021']
  .map(dateAsString => dateAsString.split('/')[1])
  .sort());
```

Answer (score 3):

simply you can use `map` method to iterate over your array and then get every element and split them or separate them using `Regex`.

```js
const array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];

// separate each data into month and year and get the years in the result array
const result = array1.map(data => data.split("/")[1])

// make years uinque with this simple hack 
const uniqueResult = [...new Set(result)]

// now you can sort your the data 
const sortedUniqueResult = uniqueResult.sort((a, b) => a - b)

console.log(sortedUniqueResult)
```

You can also use **javascript methods chaining** to convert the above snippet into one line of code:

```js
const array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];

const result = [...new Set(array1.map(data => data.split("/")[1]).sort((a, b) => a - b))]
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to iterate through the array split the string into month and year and return only the year: (`~~` converts string into integer)

```js
var array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];

var years = [...new Set(array1.map(e => ~~e.split("/")[1]))];

console.log(years.sort())
```

Answer (score 2):

Logic

- Loop through array
- Generate the year array by splitting the data on `/`.
- Generate unique items using `Array.reduce`
- Sort the array.

```js
const array1 = ['9/2022', '7/2020', '11/2021', '12/2020', '2/2020', '4/2021', '10/2021'];
const result = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const year = curr.split('/')[1];
  if (!acc.includes(year)) {
    acc.push(year);
  }
  return acc;
}, []).sort();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert all of your dates to strings containing the year only. You can do this using `map()` on the array and the `split()` method on each string.
Then convert the year strings into numbers by using the `parseInt()` function.
Sort the year numbers using the default `Array.sort()` method and create a new `Set` (only containing unique values from the given array).
Using the `spread operator (...)`, convert that Set into an Array.

```js
var array1 = ['9/2022','7/2020','11/2021','12/2020','2/2020','4/2021','10/2021'];

var years = [...new Set(array1.map(date => parseInt(date.split("/")[1])).sort())];
```